# How does insertOrThrow work with a UNIQUE constraint?

Tags: android, sql, database, unique

If I set a column with the UNIQUE constraint in SQL, will it then throw an error if I try to insert a value that already exists in that column when I use "insertOrThrow()"?

Basically what I'm trying to do is log ID's as they are scanned in(i.e. "1020030"), and I want to recognize when the same ID is scanned when the app is used at a later date. So if I mark the column identified as "_id" as UNIQUE, and then attempt to insert a value with the insertOrThrow() command, will it throw if the value exists because I marked it as UNIQUE? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will serve your purpose. Check android documentation on [insertOrThrow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29). By the way if you define some column as UNIQUE then for any duplicate insertion will lead to an exception
throwing by normal database concept.

Please check [sqlLite doc.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#primkeyconst)

> A UNIQUE constraint is similar to a PRIMARY KEY constraint, except that a single table may have any number of UNIQUE constraints. For each UNIQUE constraint on the table, each row must feature a unique combination of values in the columns identified by the UNIQUE constraint. As with PRIMARY KEY constraints, for the purposes of UNIQUE constraints NULL values are considered distinct from all other values (including other NULLs). If an INSERT or UPDATE statement attempts to modify the table content so that two or more rows feature identical values in a set of columns that are subject to a UNIQUE constraint, it is a constraint violation.

So you are going to get the throwable excepyion due to constrain violation and it will serve your purpose.

Note: UNIQUE constraints allow for the value NULL. However, as with any value participating in a UNIQUE constraint, only one null value is allowed per column.